# Switch from ZSH to default OS X

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, zsh, homebrew

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13476232/make-iterm2-launch-with-zsh

I used `chsh -s /bin/zsh` as described above to set zsh as default. I'd like to switch back to default standard terminal that comes with OS X instead of ZSH (at least for now and knowledge). What command would I need to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chsh -s /bin/bash` should do the trick.

Comment: Oh snap, how did I not think of that?!? Thanks, man!